# How to retrive UTF-8 Data from MSSQL via PHP to HTML

Tags: php, html, sql-server, utf-8

how can i get the UTF-8 data from the MSSQL Table. I have some names that are wrong converted. In the place where the umlat mark is I'm getting a sign like this �.
So for a name Gergö it show's Gerg�.

I'm not sure where the problem is. From the MSSQL to PHP conversion or PHP to HTML conversion. For this purpose im using the `sqlsrv` functions.

In HTML i added the meta tag `<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">` but this didn't solve the problem. I also added before the connection starts the `ini_set('mssql.charset', 'UTF-8');` function but this also didn't helped.

Comment: Ok i solved my problem i added to the connection array a `"CharacterSet" => "UTF-8"`

Comment: What is your SQL server driver? PHP version? OS version? `mssql.charset` is not effective for all drivers.